# SVN "Unable to locate auth file"

Tags: asp.net, svn, visualsvn-server, sharpsvn

I have an ASP.NET application which uses SharpSvn (SharpSvn.1.9-x86.1.9005.3940.224). The application runs on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8 with its own application pool.
The SVN server itself is VisualSVN Server 3.6.0. This server is setup to use HTTPS. Everything works like a charm.

Now I've created a second application. As well ASP.NET with the very same version of SharpSvn. I've deployed this application in a new site into the very same IIS with its own application pool. The application is running perfectly fine. Well, almost... if I try to get the history of a file which is part of the first application I get the error "Unable to locate auth file".

The stack trace is not very helpful for me:

```
[SvnException]: Unable to locate auth file
[SvnRepositoryIOException]: Unable to connect to a repository at URL &#39;https://localhost:8181/svn/tcr/kiosk/KioskSetup.xml&#39;
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error, Object targets) in d:\bb\sharpsvn-v1.900x\v40\src\sharpsvn\svnclientargs.cpp:line 78
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error, Object targets) in d:\bb\sharpsvn-v1.900x\v40\src\sharpsvn\svnclientargs.cpp:line 39
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.InternalLog(ICollection`1 targets, Uri logRoot, SvnRevision altPegRev, SvnLogArgs args, EventHandler`1 logHandler) in d:\bb\sharpsvn-v1.900x\v40\src\sharpsvn\commands\log.cpp:line 378
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Log(ICollection`1 targets, SvnLogArgs args, EventHandler`1 logHandler) in d:\bb\sharpsvn-v1.900x\v40\src\sharpsvn\commands\log.cpp:line 213
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Log(ICollection`1 targetPaths, SvnLogArgs args, EventHandler`1 logHandler) in d:\bb\sharpsvn-v1.900x\v40\src\sharpsvn\commands\log.cpp:line 267
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.GetLog(ICollection`1 targetPaths, SvnLogArgs args, Collection`1& logItems) in d:\bb\sharpsvn-v1.900x\v40\src\sharpsvn\commands\log.cpp:line 486
   at AspNetMaintenance.Versioning.VersionControlSvn.GetLog(ICollection`1 fileNamesWithPath) in D:\projects\misc\AspNetMaintenance\AspNetMaintenance\Versioning\VersionControlSVN.cs:line 330
   at AspNetMaintenance.Controllers.FileExplorerController.GetHistory(DataSourceRequest request, Guid[] files) in D:\projects\misc\AspNetMaintenance\AspNetMaintenance\Controllers\FileExplorerController.cs:line 309
```

The second application pool has full access to the directory where VisualSVN puts all its files of the repositories.

VisualSVN Server's certificate can be found in the computer's certificate store under "Trusted Root Certification Authorities". So it should be accessible by every user.

And to make things even worse: I do not have this issue on my development machine (Windows 8, IIS Express, my user has administrative privileges).

Any ideas what I forgot?

Best regards,
   Carsten

Comment: Does the error occur after you perform any operation from that computer with `svn.exe` client to access the server? E.g. from the affected machine, run `svn info https://svn.example.com/svn/MyRepo` **under the account that runs the app pool** and then try your SharpSVN-based application again. Something makes me think that your app does not properly handle authentication and creds caching. BTW, do you have Integrated Windows Authentication or Basic Windows authentication enabled on the server? Maybe both of them?

Comment: "under the account that runs the app pool"? You mean something like "login with the app pool"? AFAIK that's not possible, or?

I've restarted the machine and did not run the first application, only the one which causes the problem. Without success. So the good idea of some caching issue seems to not apply.

The authentication is set to "Integrated" for both applications. I've checked all the other settings and did not find any differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple: The property `loadUserProfile` of the IIS application pool has to be set to `true`.